# how to create a dictionary in python for unknown key:value pairs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
n = int(input())

MyDict = {}

key = []
value = []
check_key = []

for i in range(0,n):
    inp = input().split()
    key.append(inp[0])
    value.append(inp[1])

MyDict = dict(zip(key,value))

for j in range(0,n):
    check_inp = input()
    check_key.append(check_inp)

for k in check_key:
    if k in MyDict:
        print("{}={}".format(k,MyDict[k]))

    else:
        print("Not found")
```

This is all I have written

Please help me to do it more efficiently

I can't find the error in test case
can anyone please help me to figure out error

I'm stuck here for 3-Days

[problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcm0D.png)

[Test Case Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DASYN.png)

Comment: "I'm stuck in this code" Can you show us the code you've written that doesn't work? It's also quite unclear what you're asking here, how are you reading the inputs? Are they strings that should be split? Why isn't `tom=11122222` part of your sample output?`

Comment: If the line has 2 elements then `somedict["element-1"] = "element2"`, otherwise provide more details as @HampusLarsson has asked.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Actually My problem is I want to write a code that will take unknown inputs like ''sam 99912222'' and create a dictionary. "sam" as key and "99912222" as value

Comment: please check the image _/\_

Comment: @SkMdSaif This is very clearly homework, and it's okay to ask questions regarding that. [However, please read this meta-thread about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8805293) and ask yourself if you've really asked the question correctly, or if you should work on it a bit more. We can answer your homework for you, however you will most likely not learn from it if you don't at least try to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thank You. And I'm posting My work...... and updating the question.......

Answer (score 0):

It seems what youre asking is that you want to query keys in your dict and if there are no results corresponding to that key it should yield the proper message otherwise return its value. if so:

```
a = {'sam' : 99999999,
     'tom' : 11111111,
     'har' : 22222222,}

a.get('sam')
a.get('edw')
a.get('har')
```

returns:

```
99999999
None
22222222
```

Comment: Thank You. But it's not that what I'm lookinf for........

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that your tests fail is because you're not giving back a response when they are polling for `phoneNumbers`. Also Your script will also gather `n` amounts of names to check against the `phoneBook` which according to the specifications in the question it should not.

I've simplified your code a little and removed unnecessary variables:

```
# the number of entries on the phoneBook
n = int(input())

phoneBook = {}
for i in range(n):
    k, v = input().split()
    phoneBook[k] = v

while True:
    # the name to lookup in the phonebook
    name = input()
    
    # Exit condition if we don't get any input.
    if name == "":
        break
    
    # Tries to get the phoneNumber via the given name in the phoneBook
    try:
        print("{}={}".format(name,phoneBook[name]))
    # If 'name' is not inside of the dictionary, it raises an KeyError
    # which we catch here to instead just print out "Not found"
    except KeyError: 
        print("Not found")
```

Output from one of my tests:

```
3
asdasd  123123123
jkdjkjkfd 129020990201
jkasjkldlk 1991991991
kalsdkl
Not found
asdasd
asdasd=123123123
```

Try this and see if that solves the problem for you.

Comment: It is throwing an EOFError :(

Comment: But test cases are passed